# how to select rows with same column_a but different column_b?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case, window-functions

I want to select rows in sql server, there's my questions below:

```
Table1
-------------------------- 
|     Name   |    Type   |
--------------------------
|      A     |     1     |
|      A     |     2     |
|      B     |     1     |
|      B     |     3     |
|      A     |     3     |
|      C     |     1     |
|      C     |     3     |
|      D     |     1     |
|      D     |     2     |
|      D     |     3     |
|      .     |     .     |
|      .     |     .     |
```

Select rows like below:

```
Table2
-------------------------- 
|     Name   |    Type   |
--------------------------
|      A     |     1     |
|      A     |     2     |
|      A     |     3     |
|      D     |     1     |
|      D     |     2     |
|      D     |     3     |
|      .     |     .     |
|      .     |     .     |
```

The select rules is...

Show Name and Type which Type must have 1,2 and 3.

Example: A had 1,2,3 types,so i would select it.

Example: B only has 1,2 types,so i wouldn't select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `INNER JOIN`s on the three `Type` columns to achieve this:

```
SELECT Table1.[Name],
       Table1.[Type]
  FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN (
               SELECT [Name]
                 FROM Table1
                 WHERE ([Type] = 1)
               ) A ON A.[Name] = Table1.[Name]
    INNER JOIN (
               SELECT [Name]
                 FROM Table1
                 WHERE ([Type] = 2)
               ) B ON B.[Name] = A.[Name]
    INNER JOIN (
               SELECT [Name]
                 FROM Table1
                 WHERE ([Type] = 3)
               ) C ON C.[Name] = A.[Name]
```

This outputs:

```
Name    Type
A       1
A       2
A       3
D       1
D       2
D       3
```

The matching [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3d397/4).

This works by returning rows that contain `[Type] = 1`, and then ONLY matching rows where `[Type] = 2` and `[Type] = 3`.  Then this is joined back to your main table and the results are returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select name, type
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(case when type in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end)
                over(partition by name) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where cnt = 3
```

This assumes that each (name, type) tuple occurs only once in the original table, which is consistant with your sample data.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c93ea41ac971904561ec8b996b9f0b49)**:

```
name | type
:--- | ---:
A    |    1
A    |    2
A    |    3
D    |    1
D    |    2
D    |    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the names with `group by name` and set the condition in the `having` clause:

```
select * from Table1
where name in (
  select name 
  from Table1
  group by name
  having count(distinct type) = 3
)
```

If there are for the column `Type` other values than `1, 2, 3` then:

```
select * from Table1
where type in (1, 2, 3) and name in (
  select name 
  from Table1
  where type in (1, 2, 3)
  group by name
  having count(distinct type) = 3
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c746f784e3f07ba70d37c34bae48db27).

Results:

```
> Name | Type
> :--- | ---:
> A    |    1
> A    |    2
> A    |    3
> D    |    1
> D    |    2
> D    |    3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use string_agg if it is sql server 2017 and above or Azure SQL as below:

```
Select * from #yourTable yt join (
    select [name], string_agg([Type], ',') as st_types
    from #YourTable 
    group by [name] ) a 
on yt.name = a.[name] and a.st_types like '%1,2,3%'
```

Answer (score -1):

I give you this, this will work if you have:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
A 2
```

It will then only give you B.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Name in (
SELECT Name from 
(
   SELECT Name, Type, count(Name) c from Table1 where Type = 1
   GROUP BY Name, Type 
   HAVING count(Name) = 1
   UNION
   SELECT Name, Type, count(Name) c from Table1 where Type = 2
   GROUP by Name, Type 
   HAVING count(Name) = 1
   UNION
   SELECT Name, Type, count(Name) c from Table1 where Type = 3
   GROUP by Name, Type 
   HAVING  count(Name) = 1) t 
GROUP by name
HAVING count(c) = 3)
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d8493dcbcece5e4a832e33aa35987191)

Comment: Solution from @GMB does it too in much more less code :)